# How to write a Linux VFS module?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Are there good documentations or tutorials for writing a new VFS in Linux suitable for beginners?

I tried to locate some resources on web, but could not find one. As such I am not sure what  kernel DS I have to use and what concepts / modules to implement.

Comment: Have you read `<kernel-source>/linux/Documentation/filesystems/vfs.txt
`?

Comment: I did not found any file by that name:
desktop:/lib/modules/3.5.0-41-generic# find . -name "*vfs.*"
desktop:/lib/modules/3.5.0-41-generic#

Comment: Download the kernel source, its in there. Take a look at [this link](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/Documentation/filesystems/vfs.txt?id=refs/tags/v3.11.3).

Comment: `/lib/modules/<xyz>` is not the kernel source. The kernel source is usually at `/usr/src`, or you can just [download it](https://www.kernel.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

COnsider the book Linux kernel programming by Robert Love. It has got a fairly decent amount of information on VFS and start writing new one. I believe there is an ebook also available for that.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using FUSE?

http://fuse.sourceforge.net/

It is much simpler to pull this off using FUSE, and since FUSE has bindings for almost all popular languages, you can also use other languages than C. You would be interacting with the VFS via FUSE, so there's a much smaller chance of things going wrong (which would crash the whole OS). There are also more examples available for FUSE than for doing it directly using the VFS.